# Building oracles for hyperledger composer

Tags: oracle, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I just switched from building a DAPP for ETH to Hyperledger as suggested by the project supervisor. I'm very new to Hyperledger and I'm using Composed. In my previous DAPP I studied how to build an oracle that had to be used to update the prices of gold or the exchange rate (stuff that changes and has to be updated quickly). I've looked for a tutorial on how to build an oracle on Hyperledger without success. I tried to think about how that can be built after having followed the tutorials proposed in [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials) but I can't really tell how that has to be built. Can anybody tell me if they can be built and how should I structure such oracle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you want to use external data in the blockchain.

First, nothing to do with your problem, but as an advice from my personal experience, if you want to go deeper in Fabric, don't use Composer. From my understanding and my tests, composer is meant as a test thing. If you want to access all fabric elements, don't use it.

Moreover, Composer is now just updated to fit with new version of Fabric. It won't getany major update. It is not really an active project anymore. (there is an entire post from the devs about it on one of their forum)

---

**Back to your question**

Your chaincode is written in Node.js. As a consequence, you have access to all node.js packages (I have a doubt when using composer, correct me if I am wrong). 
Then you could just send HTTP requests to the  outside of your chain.

Note that Fabric allows to use a CouchDB database as a world state. I don"t know if you need to store your own data or need specifically external data, but you could use it instead of querying internet.

---

**Don't use non deterministic elements**

It is not recommended to "use" external element that you do not manage.
The reason is that the algorithm (consensus) to create a block is (and must be) extremely deterministic, contrary to ethereum/bitcoin where it is more probabilistic.

Due to the endorsement mechanism, the simulation of your chaincode must be EXACTLY the same for every endorsing peer.

Imagine you query, as an example, the temperature of a place on some API. Your first peer may get 10°c, because it queried temperature at time t, but the other peer received transaction proposal at t+1, thus the temperature changed and it got 10.01°c. The consequence is that the simulation will most likely not give the same result on both peers, and then transaction will not be valid.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes I basically need another party that is able to gather external data and input it in the blockchain, so even if, say, at time t0 we have the price of gold at X, that's the info I need and I do not care if at t1 it changed to something different because I will have to decide what to do based on the price of gold at t0. I basically need to transfer goods/money from one party to another based on some external factors (such as the price of gold for example), thus is it correct that I need such third party "oracle" that inputs deterministic data in the blockchain?

Comment: @Masiar You need to care what will be the price at t+1, if you have more than one peer that endorse the transaction. As I stated, if peer 0 and peer 1 have different outcomes (based on the different price of gold they got), your transaction will never be valid because of said different simulation. You should check how the endorsement process works and/or adapt your endorsement policy correctly or implement a system to make sure you get the price of gold of a certain time.

Comment: In my idea both parties won't have access to the price of gold: there will be a third party defining the price of gold (if this is possible). I would like it to work as a smart contract: my logic will exchange goods/money from one party to another based on the external world data. I'm still a lot into the ETH mentality of oracles and smart contract and I am not sure this can be ported 1:1 to what hyperledger offers...

Comment: @Masiar Ok. So what you need to define is: Do you REALLY need to have external data? Can't everything be managed inside you blockchain? Are you familiar enough will all concepts? Many of them change quite a lot from the one you've learnt from public blockchains.

Comment: We definitely need external data because some of the computations that decide where the goods/money (especially money) go depends on some computations that need external data such as stock exchange, price of raw materials, and exchange rates...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take some inspiration from Oraclize's approach. Their integration with Hyperledger Fabric is fully open source. Their approach is described here: https://docs.oraclize.it/#fabric

The source code is documented on Github:

- Connector Chaincode:
  https://github.com/oraclize/fabric-api/blob/master/connector/oraclize-connector.js
- Currency exchange example:
  https://github.com/oraclize/fabric-examples/blob/master/eurusd-example/chaincode/go/user-chaincode.go